# Inserting multiple rows (single query) to MySQL in PHP: Prepare-Execute vs. Prepare-Bind-Execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, prepare

I'm writing some PHP to accept an array of numbers and names in **POST** and insert them into a MySQL table (named ***Contacts_table***) Here's the version that works fine without any error:

```
<?php

  // Includes
  require_once 'Admin/Connector.php';

  // Test if payload exists
  if($_POST){

  // Read payload into arrays
      $ar = 0;
      foreach($_POST as $entry){
          $namenum = explode(',', $entry);
          $names[$ar] = $namenum[1];
          $numbers[$ar] = $namenum[0];
          $ar += 1;
      }
      $namenum = NULL;

  // Build SQL query
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO Contact_table (NAME, PHONE) VALUES ';
      $insertQuery = array();
      $insertData = array();
      $n = 0;
      foreach ($numbers as $num) {
        $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
        $insertData[] = $names[$n];
        $insertData[] = $num;
        $n++;
      }
      $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
      $sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = COALESCE(VALUES(name), name);';
      $n = NULL;
      $num = NULL;

  // Connect to MySQL database
      $connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,PROJDB,PROJDBUSER,PROJDBPWD);

  // Execute SQL query
      $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute($insertData);
      $insertQuery = NULL;
      $insertData = NULL;
      $sql = NULL;
      $query = NULL;

  // Close connection to MySQL database
      $connect = NULL;

  }

?>
```

However, as you can see, I'm not using the **bindParam()** function here and just feeding the values directly to the **execute()** function. Many have recommended that I use **bindParam()** instead for server performance gains. Is it true or I am better off with this program as it stands? I did try writing and running a version of the above code using bindParam:

```
<?php

  // Includes
  require_once 'Admin/Connector.php';

  // Test if payload exists
  if($_POST){

  // Read payload into arrays
      $ar = 0;
      foreach($_POST as $entry){
          $namenum = explode(',', $entry);
          $names[$ar] = $namenum[1];
          $numbers[$ar] = $namenum[0];
          $ar += 1;
      }
      $namenum = NULL;

  // Build SQL query
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO Contact_table (NAME, PHONE) VALUES ';
      $insertQuery = array();
      $insertData = array();
      $n = 0;
      foreach ($numbers as $num) {
        $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
        $insertData[] = $names[$n];
        $insertData[] = $num;
        $n++;
      }
      $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
      $sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = COALESCE(VALUES(name), name);';
      $n = NULL;
      $num = NULL;

  // Connect to MySQL database
      $connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,PROJDB,PROJDBUSER,PROJDBPWD);

   // Prepare SQL query 
      $query = $connect->prepare($sql);

  // Bind variables
      foreach($insertData as $key => &$ins) {
          $connect->bindParam($key+1,$ins);
      }

  // Execute SQL query
      $query->execute();
      $insertQuery = NULL;
      $insertData = NULL;
      $sql = NULL;
      $query = NULL;
      $key = NULL;
      $ins = NULL;

  // Close connection to MySQL database
      $connect = NULL;

  }

?>
```

But this code refuses to run and returns a fatal error – ***Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()***. What am I doing wrong here? I understand it's possible to write a much simpler code if I include **execute()** within the loop but that would spawn multiple queries which I want to avoid at all costs. My goal is a single query no matter what.

Comment: I don't think there is any efficiency gain, but I have not ever benchmarked these kinds of comparisons.

Comment: Regarding "simpler code if execute in loop": In my experience in other (.Net) languages, as long as the query is "prepared" the performance differences are negligible between multiple execution vs a "bulk" insert query. There are added benefits to multi-execute, like having to worry much much less about the query itself becoming to long for your connector.

Comment: ...and by "query itself" I meant the query string.

Comment: @uueerdo thanks for your explanation. However, performance gains aside, don't many hosting providers stipulate a certain cap on the number of transactions you can perform per day? I remember having recently read on Amazon Cloud's website that they charge you by the transaction albeit the cap is high and they offer MongoDb. Not sure what Mysql hosts do though. That's my only apprehension.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia, I am not familiar with hosting rates; all the development I do is based around "in house" servers. I can imagine trying to develop around such constraints would be frustrating. I would think/hope that such hosts wouldn't necessarily define 1 query = 1 transaction; but like I said, I am blissfully unfamiliar with such limitations. (Perhaps if you began the set of queries with "START TRANSACTION;" and ended them with "END TRANSACTION;"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't  `$connect->bindParam($key+1,$ins);`. Because PDO object doesn't have such method. Only PDOStatement has. That is why you've got error message.

You should :

```
 $query->bindValue($key+1,$ins);
```

And you should use `bindValue` because if not, all your inserted values  will get same value (the last one of $ins before you call `execute`).